# Why does Thunderbird display huge numbers?

Tags: linux-mint, thunderbird

Thunderbird is displaying **huge** numbers in it's UI. I've tried changing it in the 'Display>Formatting' settings, as well as creating a userChrome.css file, but neither had an effect. This doesn't seem to be affecting any other program.

[image: test email]
[image: display settings]

Comment: Those large white digits, displayed partially cut off, certainly look like a bug. Do the values they display make any sense; are they related on some way to the rest of what Thunderbird is doing?

Comment: They are displaying correct information, just really large.

Comment: Oh, right, I see that now: the huge "11" in your last screenshot really is the value of the "Size" dropdown. Hopefully someone here will know how to debug this kind of thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by running `apt-get remove <package>` for every font I installed manually.